# Rails mountable CMS and or Blog engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, content-management-system, rubygems, blogs

I am looking for a mountable CMS engine that I can attach to my rails 3 app.  I would like to do something like:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  mount Resque::Server, :at => "/resque"             # This already exists and is awesome
  mount SomeAwesomeCMS::Server, :at => '/docs'
  mount SomeAwesomeBlog::Server, :at => '/blog'
end
```

Anyone have any positive experiences?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing and found ComfortableMexicanSofa: https://github.com/twg/comfortable-mexican-sofa

It can't be mounted as an engine but it was the most simple one I found.

Ps, links and reasoning to use ComfortableMexicanSofa I found from here: 
http://jeffpoulton.com/2011/09/managing-static-content-in-a-ruby-on-rails-application/)

Comment: Totally mountable as of 1.8.0

Answer (score 1):

People have [done it before with NestaCMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867491/is-it-possble-include-nesta-cms-into-rails3-application).

If you don't technically need to go through Rack mounts, [RefineryCMS](http://refinerycms.com/) is a Rails 3 app that will work inside your app.

I also think [BrowserCMS](http://www.browsercms.org/) was working towards being able to mount it as a Rack app, but I don't think that work is done yet.

Answer (score 1):

LocomotiveCMS and RefineryCMS are both working on switching to mountable engine. Locomotive has a branch for it and Refinery's master is what you might want. Both seems great and are pretty different!

I started some work on a basic blog engine that'll be a mountable engine. I'll open source it as soon as I have something satisfying to show and once I use it for myself in production. I'll update here when I open source it.

EDIT: you can now try to use [Monologue](http://github.com/jipiboily/monologue).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only real requirement for this would be that the blog engine is built on Rack. You'd probably want to dig around in Google and Stackoverflow to see which ones are Rack compliant. I did a quick search and the only one I could find was http://ruby-slippers.heroku.com/

More blogs can be found here, although I'm not sure if any are Rack based.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709933/what-ruby-blog-engines-are-there