# Nesta CMS and Rails3 integration: menu is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, content-management-system, nestacms

I already made some successfully experiments integrating nesta with rails 3 (see [Is it possble include Nesta CMS into Rails3 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867491/is-it-possble-include-nesta-cms-into-rails3-application) and [Nesta CMS and Rails3 integration: adding blog to an exiting rails 3 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167096/nesta-cms-and-rails3-integration-adding-blog-to-an-exiting-rails-3-application))

But than, I needed a menu on the right side of the blog, like explained in "[Working with menus](http://nestacms.com/docs/creating-content/menus)"

To give it a try, I built the famous content-demo site with `nesta demo:content`, but all links appearing on the right side, which are coming from content-demo/menu.txt, are broken because related to the main Rails app (http://example.com) and not to the embedded nesta blog (http://example.com/blog)

Here it is my current file configs, the integration is between Rails 3.0.10 and Nesta 0.9.10 :

config/routes.rb

```
  match '/blog' => Nesta::App
  match '/css/*style.css' => Nesta::App
  match '/attachments/*file' => Nesta::App
  root :to => "home#index"
```

UPDATE:

using `mount Nesta::App, :at => '/blog'` instead of `match '/blog' => Nesta::App` rich the same result ...

config/initializers/nesta.rb

```
require "nesta/env"
require "nesta/app"
Nesta::Env.root = ::File.expand_path("../../nesta-blog", File.dirname(__FILE__))
Nesta::App.root = ::File.expand_path("../../nesta-blog", File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

nesta-blog/config/config.yml

```
...
content: nesta-blog/content-demo
...
```

I thought was depending by how nesta built the relative path of menu's liks and that was depending on `base_url` method in `nesta-0.9.10/lib/nesta/app.rb`.

Than I tried unpacking locally nesta-0.9.10 changing `url = "http://#{request.host}"` in `url = "http://#{request.host}/blog"`:

```
  def base_url
    url = "http://#{request.host}/blog"
    request.port == 80 ? url : url + ":#{request.port}"
  end
```

put `gem 'nesta', :path => 'vendor/gems/nesta-0.9.10'` on Gemfile and `build update nesta` but no, doesn't work.

UPDATE:

Also few tries with `Nesta::Menu.for_path('/')` in `./vendor/gems/nesta-0.9.10/lib/nesta/app.rb`

```
  def set_common_variables
    @menu_items = Nesta::Menu.for_path('/')
    @site_title = Nesta::Config.title
    set_from_config(:title, :subtitle, :google_analytics_code)
    @heading = @title
  end
```

didn't get results.

My nesta-blog/content-demo/menu.txt don't currently refers to the home page (like in default generation with `nesta demo:content`):

```
marking-up-pages
  examples/using-markdown
  examples/using-textile
  examples/using-haml
  adding-attachments
menu-editing
publishing-a-feed
```

and if I try putting on top something like :

`/` or `/blog` or `/nesta-blog` the menu disappear ...

So my question is, how does it work ? 
Do you have any suggestion / workaround ?

Thanks in advance
Luca G. Soave

Answer (score 0):

Did you try mounting Nesta, instead of justing matching a route (as described in [Nesta CMS and Rails3 integration: adding blog to an exiting rails 3 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167096/nesta-cms-and-rails3-integration-adding-blog-to-an-exiting-rails-3-application))?

I would expect that `mount` in `routes.rb` might deal with all these relative path issues for you.

I think stack overflow is great, but I suspect you'll do better with this stuff on the Nesta mailing list. The number of people who use Nesta who see your posts on here will be relatively small...

Comment: Yes I tried.  mount Nesta::App, :at => '/blog' works the same way and this sound strange to me too after I read the following article: http://library.edgecase.com/Rails/2011/01/04/rails-routing-and-rack-endpoints.html but the two ways don't affect menu's relative path. Moreover everything else works fine ...

Comment: ... i use mount Nesta::App, :at => '/blog' and not mount Nesta::App, :at => '/' because I already have root :to => "home#index" which route the main Rails3 app ...